# Choose best samples to get strongest model

Tags: model-selection

I am looking to create a model to best predict the presence of a particular species based on a number of habitat covariates. I have mapped out a couple of these covariates and am looking for a way to choose sites with a strong mix of these covariates (in order to maximize my chance of getting a strong model with less sampling for the species itself).

My covariate table is like this

LocNum--Cov1---Cov2

1------------70------560

2------------30------620

3------------20------100

4-----------120------60

5-----------100------30

Etc.....

LocNum is just a unique identifier for each location. I am looking to do this before I gather information on the presence/absence of a particular species. However in the end I would like to use these covariates to provide a probability of occurrence of a species.

Is there a statistical method (preferably in R) that allows me to choose a set number of Location that will maximize variation in my covariates.

I am sorry if my stats lingo is poor.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you clarify - What is LocNum? Is there a variable representing the presence of the species that's not shown here?

Comment: LocNum is just a unique identifier for each location. I am looking to do this before I gather information on the presence/absence of a particular species. However in the end I would like to use these covariates to provide a probability of occurrence of a species. The sampling for species occurrence is expensive and time intensive so I am hoping to get sites that maximize my chance of getting a strong model.

Answer (score 1):

My direct answer to your question is "No" -- there is no established method for doing this.  With continuous predictors, it would seem straightforward to assess covariate variability in each candidate location using standard deviation or variance.  But I'd ask you to think about what a "strong model" means.  It sounds as if you will be trying to maximize in-sample predictive accuracy at the expense of generalizeability, i.e., of out-of-sample accuracy.  Wouldn't you rather choose locations that will best allow you to generalize to a wide population?  (Or maybe you are looking for an idealized scenario because only that will allow you to fully explore certain causal relationships.)